# Monks precepts - Not to teach dhamma to women and not to recite dhamma in pali with laymen?

Tags: vinaya, precept

Two of the Pacittiyas (monks precepts according to Vinaya) implies that 1-Bhikkhus should not teach more than 6 words of Dhamma to women and also 2-Should not recite texts of dhamma in pali with laymen.

Is this correct? I may have read that in a non reliable source of per haps I may have misinterpreted it, it could also be an issue with the translation... not sure.

Anyway, I woukd like to understand it better. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think your first doubt was taken out of context from the following rule (excerpt from [The Buddhist Monastic Code](http://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/BMC_v140110.pdf), page 370):

> *Should any bhikkhu teach more than five or six sentences of Dhamma to
>   a woman, unless a knowledgeable man is present, it is to be confessed.*
>
> “Then Ven. Udāyin, dressing early in the
>   morning and taking his bowl and (outer) robe, went to visit a certain
>   family. At that time the lady of the house was sitting in the main
>   entrance, while the daughter-in-law was sitting in the door to the
>   inner chamber. So Ven. Udāyin went to the lady of the house… and
>   whispered Dhamma into her ear. The daughter-in-law thought, ‘Is this
>   monk my mother-in-law’s lover, or is he being fresh with her?’ Then,
>   having whispered Dhamma into the ear of the lady of the house, Ven.
>   Udāyin went to the daughter-inlaw… and whispered Dhamma into her ear.
>   The lady of the house thought, ‘Is this monk my daughter-in-law’s
>   lover, or is he being fresh with her?’ After whispering Dhamma into
>   the daughter-in-law’s ear, Ven. Udāyin left. So the lady of the house
>   said to the daughter-in-law, ‘Hey. What did that monk say to you?’
>
> “‘He taught me Dhamma, ma’am. And what did he say to you?’
>
> “‘He taught me Dhamma, too.’
>
> “So they criticized and complained and spread it
>   about, ‘How can Ven. Udāyin whisper Dhamma into women’s ears?
>   Shouldn’t the Dhamma be taught openly and out loud?’”
>
> The two factors for the full offense here are:
>
> 1) Object: a female human being who knows what is and is not lewd, what is well-spoken and ill-spoken, and who has not asked one a question about the Dhamma.
>
> 2) Effort: One teaches her more than six sentences of Dhamma without a knowledgeable man present—i.e., a male human being who also knows what is and is not lewd, what is well-spoken and ill-spoken.
>
> ...
>
> *Summary: Teaching more than six sentences of Dhamma to a woman,
>   except in response to a question, is a pācittiya offense unless a knowledgeable
>   man is present.*

Your second doubt, seems to be referring to this rule (excerpt from [The Buddhist Monastic Code](http://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/BMC_v140110.pdf), page 356):

> *Should any bhikkhu have an unordained person recite Dhamma line by line (with him), it is to be confessed.*
>
> This is an offense with two factors:
>
> 1) Effort: One gets a student to recite Dhamma line-by-line with oneself (which, as we shall see below, means to train the student to be a skilled reciter of a Pali Dhamma
>   text).
>
> 2) Object: The student is neither a bhikkhu nor a bhikkhunī.
>
> ...
>
> *Summary: To train a novice or lay person to recite passages of Dhamma by
>   rote is a pācittiya offense.*